# Does 'ros2 set param' exist?

Tags: ros, ros2, parameter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If not, is there a way to declare a global parameter for all nodes?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/326449/does-%27ros2-set-param%27-exist?/) by [ahtsan](https://answers.ros.org/users/43242/ahtsan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 112 on 2019-06-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Parameters are per node in ROS 2. There is no a global parameter server like ROS 1. It is possible to set a param on a node with `ros2 param set`

```
$ ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp parameter_blackboard &
...
$ ros2 param set /parameter_blackboard foo bar
Set parameter successful
$ ros2 param list /parameter_blackboard
  foo
  use_sim_time
```

If you'd like to set a parameter on all running nodes, you'll need to enumerate them and set the parameter on each one. If you would like to set a parameter on a lot of nodes that you're launching, the parameter [should be passed into each `launch_ros.actions.Node`](https://github.com/ros2/launch_ros/blob/c86ee0b7c74af84c3b54eebede1501b7735431df/launch_ros/launch_ros/actions/node.py#L61).

```
import launch
import launch_ros


def generate_launch_description():
    use_sim_time = launch.substitutions.LaunchConfiguration('use_sim_time', default=False)

    return launch.LaunchDescription(
        [
            launch_ros.actions.Node(
                package='demo_nodes_cpp', node_executable='talker',
                node_name='talker',
                parameters=[{'use_sim_time': use_sim_time}]),
            launch_ros.actions.Node(
                package='demo_nodes_cpp', node_executable='listener',
                node_name='listener',
                parameters=[{'use_sim_time': use_sim_time}]),
        ])
```

I used a `LaunchConfiguration` in this example. You can give it a value on the command line

```
$ ros2 launch example_launch.py use_sim_time:=True
...
$ ros2 param get /listener use_sim_time
Boolean value is: True
```

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) with karma: 3061 on 2019-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahtsan](https://answers.ros.org/users/43242/ahtsan/) on 2019-06-20**:
Perfect. Does `ros2 param set /node_name key value` trigger the `on_parameter_event` if a `SyncParametersClient` is defined inside the node? What I want to achieve is to perform some tasks if a parameter is true in the node.

**Comment by [ahtsan](https://answers.ros.org/users/43242/ahtsan/) on 2019-06-20**:
I am answering to my own question: Yes, it does.

**Comment by [ahtsan](https://answers.ros.org/users/43242/ahtsan/) on 2019-06-20**:
We can pass argument to set the parameter value for launch file. Is it possible when we run a standalone node? like `ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp parameter_blackboard foo:=true`.

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2019-06-20**:
It doesn't seem to be possible at the moment.
But it is listed on the feature list for the next ROS 2 distribution: https://github.com/ros2/ros2/issues/734

> passing key-value parameters on CLI

**Comment by [ahtsan](https://answers.ros.org/users/43242/ahtsan/) on 2019-06-20**:
Can I use the same node for another `rclcpp::SyncParametersclient`?
I have a node named `foo_node` running and do

```
void Foo::init()
{
  auto parameters_client = std::make_shared<rclcpp::SyncParametersClient>(this);

  this->declare_parameter("foo");

  auto sub = parameters_client->on_parameter_event(
    [this](const rcl_interfaces::msg::ParameterEvent::SharedPtr event) -> void
    {
      for (auto & changed_param : event->changed_parameters)
        if (changed_param.name == "foo")
        {
          RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Foo is set");
        }
    });
}
```

and when I run `ros2 set param /foo_node foo true` in another process, the callback is not triggered but instead it logs `[INFO] [Logger]: Hey`.

Any thoughts?

**Comment by [ahtsan](https://answers.ros.org/users/43242/ahtsan/) on 2019-06-20**:
I am answering my self again: I have to make sure there is at least one reference to `sub`, otherwise it destroy itself.